# jQuery keydown callback listens only on outer <ul> rather than inner <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Hey so here is the code demo I made

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul contenteditable class="outerList">
<li class="innerElement">Hello</li>
<li class="innerElement">World</li>
<li class="innerElement">Hello World</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(".outerList").keydown(function () {
      console.log("I am the outer ul");
    });
    $(".innerElement").keydown(function() {
      console.log("I am an inner element");
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the jsFiddle to run it

http://jsfiddle.net/scrbovyr/

Basically I have a content editable UL and I want to catch the enter key and pass in my own custom function. But I need to know which LI element the keydown event was thrown on. And as shown in the demo, I can only seem to tie a keydown event listener (or any event listener for that matter) to the outer UL element. Is there a way to attach the keydown event to each LI? Or is there at least a way to attach it to the UL but still tell which child it came from?

Thanks in advance, let me know if any additional information would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add `contenteditable` to your `li` elements in order to achieve that. You are setting `contenteditable` to your `ul` element, thus, the event will be binded to that element, you may edit the `li` elements, but they do not have `contenteditable` set, so the keyboard events  won't be triggered for those elements.

```
<ul class="outerList">
    <li contenteditable class="innerElement">Hello</li>
    <li contenteditable class="innerElement">World</li>
    <li contenteditable class="innerElement">Hello World</li>
</ul>
```

And then:

```
$(".innerElement").keydown(function() {
  console.log("I am an inner element");
});
```

Comment: So the reason I didnt do this prior was because I wanted to be able to have the enter key add a new row. But I guess I just have to override enter to add the row manually? How do I move the cursor down to the new row after enter is pressed?

Regardless, since you're right and I'm pretty sure this is the only way to do this, I'll mark as accepted. Thanks!!

Comment: @taxicala - you have a better explaination. :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :). If you want to add a new row just clone it or create it with jQuery, and after I suppose triggering the focus event on the newly appended li should do the trick to move the cursor to it :)

Answer (score 2):

### You may check the node at the current selection

If you don't want to make each `li` a `contenteditable` element, you may get the element at the current selection or caret position and perform a check against it.

The embedded example shows how you would achieve this using the [Web API Interface for `contenteditable` selections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). *(I tested this in Chrome, but it may need additional logic to achieve cross-browser compatibility).*

It is also worth noting that you *can* bind *some* event listeners to the children of a `contenteditable` element. For example, the `click` event may be bound to the `li` elements as you can see in the embedded example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    function getCurrentNode() {
        var node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        return node.nodeType === 1 ? node : node.parentNode;     
    }
    $('.outerList').on('click keyup', function (e) {
        var $target  = $(getCurrentNode()),
            $closest = $target.closest('b');
        console.log(e.type);
        console.log('I am the outer ul');
        console.log($target);
        
        // Optional. Filter by clostest selector.
        if ($closest.length) {
            console.log('Target matches selector', $closest);
        }
    });
    $('.innerElement').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log(e.type);
        console.log('I am an inner element');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul contenteditable class="outerList">
      <li class="innerElement">Hello</li>
      <li class="innerElement"><i>Hello</i></li>
      <li class="innerElement"><b><i>Hello</i></b></li>
      <li class="innerElement"><b>Hello</b></li>
      <li class="innerElement">Hello</li>
      <li class="innerElement">Hello</li>
  </ul>
```